# how to add a string to a binary operation then save it to a .dat file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to make a binary operation then add 0b to it then save it into an output.dat file. for example 0b1101. But it seems like binary operation overrides itself to the 0b.

```
#!/bin/bash
binary="0b"
while IFS=" ," read  i1 i2 i3 #assigns each line into three seperate entity.
do
    #checks if it's in binary, decimal or hexadecimal
    if [[ $i1 == *"0b"* ]]; then #binary
            i1=${i1//$binary/}
            i3=${i3//$binary/}
            if [ "$i2" = "+" ]; then
                    echo "0b" >$HOME/Desktop/Homework_1/output.dat
                    echo "ibase=2;obase=2; $i1+$i3" | bc -l 
                  >$HOME/Desktop/Homework_1/output.dat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors here:

First, you're redirecting both outputs with `>`. You should be aware that this will clear the content of the target file before writing. To append, use `>>` as the redirection operator:

```
echo "ibase=2;obase=2; $i1+$i3" | bc -l >> $HOME/Desktop/Homework_1/output.dat
#                                       ^^
```

Second, there's another issue with your `bc` calculation: You cannot specify `obase=2` **after** `ibase=2`. You should change it into this:

```
echo "obase=2;ibase=2; $i1+$i3" | bc -l
# specify obase first
```

You can read more about this issue here @>> [bc: Why does `ibase=16; obase=10; FF` returns FF and not 255?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/464808/211239)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I run the code now it gives me an output  like this: 0b and 1111 in a newline. But I want to add these to each other as 0b1111. I tried echo -n "obase=2;ibase=2; $i1+$i3" | bc -l but it gaved a syntax error.

Comment: @Murat Change `echo "0b"` to `echo -n "0b"`.